# 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve' error for django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication, django-1.8

I am using django's login views,but after I set the urls,I'm getting the error.I have searched on the internet but can not solve this problem.

## urls

#### project urls (this is the urls for the project)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

#### users urls(this is the urls for the users app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

#### learning_logs urls(this is the urls for the learning_logs app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home Page
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    # Show all topics
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Show topic detail, r tells django to interpret the string as raw string
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    url(r'^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$',views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    url(r'^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
]
```

## traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/users/login

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'learning_logs',
 'users')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  108.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_request
  74.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  647.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  522.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  368.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  368.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/login
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

## I tried to change the project urls and it works,why?

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.views import login

extra_patterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name' : 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
]

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^users/', include(extra_patterns, namespace='users')),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

Comment: Do you have any other urls?

Comment: @Sayse No,these are all the urls.

Comment: None at all? your base urls is trying to import from two other sources?

Comment: @Sayse I'm sorry,I forgot that,I'll update the urls